# Acumatica API Issue

Tags: acumatica

I have generated Acumatica WSDL using Acumatica site, and using same url in my applcation as a web reference.

Sample Code:

```
   string dynamicUrl = "generatedwsdl.asmx";
    serviceInstance = new AcumaticaTest.Screen();
    serviceInstance.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    serviceInstance.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    serviceInstance.EnableDecompression = true;
    serviceInstance.Timeout = 1000000;
    serviceInstance.Url = dynamicUrl;

LoginResult result = serviceInstance.Login(txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "@" + txtCompanyId.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text);
```

after above code my login is successful but when working with any Acumatica' object , I am facing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

for example:

```
CS202000Content objCS202000 = serviceInstance.CS202000GetSchema();//line 1
            serviceInstance.CS202000SetSchema(objCS202000);//line 2
            serviceInstance.CS202000Clear(); line 3
```

in line 3 I am getting below error:

{"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\n   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.GetMapping(String screenId)\n   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Clear(String id)\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---"}

Thanks

Comment: did you check whtr the webservice generated have that particular function [CS202000Clear()] inside?

Comment: Yes. please see below generated code:  [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.acumatica.com/generic/CS202000/Clear", RequestNamespace="http://www.acumatica.com/generic/", ResponseNamespace="http://www.acumatica.com/generic/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        public void CS202000Clear() {
            this.Invoke("CS202000Clear", new object[0]);
        }

Comment: can u comment line # 2 ? i used this without setting any schema.